# How do I stop Visual Studio from creating pdb debug folders?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I'm not sure what changed, but, within the directory where my solution is Visual Studio is creating debug folders.

Here are some of the folders and files being created:

```
System.Web.Http.pdb/EA80649BB72046E989099D4826726FH83/System.Web.Http.pdb
System.Web.pdb/CG58649BB72046E989099D4826726BHEWL/System.Web.Http.pdb
System.Transactions.pdb/FD28649BB72046E989099D4826726BV8F/System.Web.Http.pdb
System.Xml.pdb/5NIL649BB72046E989099D48267267CD1/System.Web.Http.pdb
```

Is there a setting I can change to stop these folders from being created?  It's cluttering up my solution directory.

Comment: Are you building in debug mode?

Comment: @aclear16 - Yes, but, I've done that for years without this result.

Comment: Project properties, Linker/Debugging check the option "Generate Program Database File". Is it `$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb`?

Comment: Those symbols look like they were downloaded from the public Microsoft symbol server. Did you configure Visual Studio to use the Microsoft symbol server to aid debugging?

Comment: In VS2010, the symbols are configured in Debug | Option and Settings... | Debugging | Symbols. Also make sure your _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable doesn't have a reference to msdl.microsoft.com.

Comment: @sergmat - I don't see this option in 2012.  I must be overlooking it.

Comment: @MarcSherman - Where can I check that variable?  I did have the Microsoft symbol server enabled, but, I've been using that for a long time without these folders being generated.

Comment: Is Symbols > `Cache symbols in this directory:` field empty?

Comment: Open a command prompt and type `set`. This will list all your environment variables. On my machine, _NT_SYMBOL_PATH appears last in the list (maybe because of the leading underscore).

Comment: @sergmat - Yes, that field is empty.

Comment: @MarcSherman - I get a lot of output, but, NT_SYMBOL_PATH is not in there.  I see HOMEDRIVE, LOGONSERVER, USERNAME, etc.

Comment: type `set _NT_SYMBOL_PATH`

Comment: @sergmat - `Environment variable _NT_SYMBOL_PATH not defined`

Comment: try set directory `Symbols > Cache symbols in this directory: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache` or `set _nt_symbol_path
_NT_SYMBOL_PATH=srv**http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`

Comment: Thanks @sergmat, I'll give that a try.  Feel free to leave that as an answer and I'll accept it in a few days if everything looks good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Debug -> Option and Settings -> Debugging -> SymbolsSymbols -> Cache symbols in this directory: try set path something like `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache`

or/and `set _nt_symbol_path _NT_SYMBOL_PATH=srv**http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`

[Troubleshooting Symbol Problems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385766.aspx):
run `vsperfreport /debugsympath` at a command line to display a complete list of the locations where profiler components are loading symbol information and whether the symbol files that are used match the files that your project is using.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms241613.aspx) topic describes how find and specify the symbol files.

Comment: I had to (surprise, surprise) restart VS to get the SymbolCache folder setting to stick.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem. Turned out the network share that I had selected for symbol cache was offline/unavailable...

Comment: Similarly, I had this issue because the folder path for "Cache symbols in this directory" was invalid.  Must have happened when I ported Visual Studio settings to a new computer...

Answer (score 2):

I’ve encountered this phenomenon too. After many try, I’ve solved it very simply, just by unchecking the Microsoft Symbols Servers checkbox in Tools/Options, Debug/Symbols.